# User Laravel model to query using an array

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, models

I've got a Laravel model, but i'd like to search the table according to an array passed in.

i.e. "Return all rows whose id matches one of the array's contents"

I can see with Laravel's query builder i can search via an input array:

```
$users = DB::table('teams')->whereIn('id', array(1, 2, 3))->get();
```

But can't seem to find anywhere how to do the same using a model.

Any ideas? Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace `DB::table('teams')->` with a static call to the model.

```
$users = <model name>::whereIn('id', array(1, 2, 3))->get();
```

Comment: You are a beautiful man! Very quick answer as well, just took me ages to get my DB connections all sorted out!

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

```
<?php
use App\Models\Team;

$users = Team::whereIn('id', array(1, 2, 3))->get();
```